# Power off from Panel menu doesn't work

Tags: release-hera, shutdown, menu

If I use shutdown options from Panel menu (indicators: session) it shows the shutdown options:

### [image]

no matter if I click shutdown or reboot, the system doesn't do anything. It doesn't care.

Shutdown in terminal works (with sudo): e.g.

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Is there a property to set? I did already search, but I didn't found...

Thank you for your inputs.

---

Update:
syslog:

> wingpanel[1855]: session_widgets_userbox_update_state: assertion 'self
>   != NULL' failed 
>   wingpanel[1855]: EndSessionDialog.vala:177: Unable to
>   shutdown:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InteractiveAuthorizationRequired:
>   Interactive authentication required.

---

Update:
Would it help if I add shutdown in sudoers.d/File? So no authentification would be needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to avoid this, but after installing new nvidia-340 driver the "shutdown"-button in the menu works.

driver version: nvidia-340 340.108

Now, I have a little problem the screen resolution in the login screen is not correct (or sometimes the wallpaper). But I think this is to fix soon. ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you could give some more information I could help you.

By this I mean, if you modified something or installed an app before it happened.

Regards.

Comment: Oh sorry, I can't remember. I got this behaviour already several weeks.
What I can say: sometimes it works. But very rarely.

I already tried to find something in log files. maybe it's something about permissions. Maybe you can give me a hint which log or what kind of entries I can check

specially is: I installed Citrix Workspace app (for remote access).